# Where's my ImageViews?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a horizontal `LinearLayout` (inside of another `LinearLayout`) containing a few `ImageView`s. For some reason I'm just just not seeing them when I run the app.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="A bunch of text"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" android:background="#0000FF"/>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
             android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:background="#0000FF"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you can see the `TextView` then? `LinearLayout`s are horizontal by default. This might be happening because Android is trying to draw the `ImageView`s to the right of the `TextView` when I'm guessing you want them below it. Try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to the outer `LinearLayout` and removing `android:orientation="horizontal"` from the inner `LinearLayout` (well, you don't *need* to remove it).

Answer (score 1):

try to change the `android:orientation` of your `LinearLayout` to `vertical` and it will fixe the problem , because the orientation horizontal , it pisses the imageviews out of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to layout your view, your code looks okay to me, at least those imageviews should show up.  Are you sure your image sources ( image1, image2.. ) are not just some plain colors that are same as background color?